# Почему спецификаторы "f" и "F" не выводят день недели в русской локали

Tags: c#, .net

Не могу найти в документации какой спецификатор формата даты выводит дату с названием дня недели на русском языке. В MSDN про спецификаторы "f" и "F" написано:

> 2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Monday, June 15, 2009 (en-US)
>
> 2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 15 июня 2009 г. (ru-RU)
>
> 2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Montag, 15. Juni 2009 (de-DE)
>
> 2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> den 15 juni 2009 13:45 (sv-SE)
>
> 2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> О”ОµП…П„О*ПЃО±, 15 О™ОїП…ОЅОЇОїП… 2009 1:45 ОјОј (el-GR)

Т.е. название дня недели в дате выводится для всех языков кроме русского.

На VS2015, .NET 4.6.1 имею такой вывод:

```
Console.WriteLine( "День недели: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString( "dddd", new CultureInfo( "ru-RU" ) ) );
Console.WriteLine( "Дата: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString( "F", new CultureInfo( "ru-RU" ) ) );
Console.WriteLine( "Дата: {0}", DateTime.Now.ToString( "f", new CultureInfo( "ru-RU" ) ) );

// Output:
//День недели: суббота
//Дата: 17 декабря 2016 г. 16:41:04
//Дата: 17 декабря 2016 г. 16:41
```

Это баг библиотеки, "так задумано" или я неправильно форматирую?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спецификаторы форматирования бывают [Стандартные](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#FullDateShortTime) и [Пользовательские](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx). Если указан стандартный спецификатор форматирования, то паттерн для преобразования значения в строку берется из настроек операционной системы. Пользовательские спецификаторы, наоборот, позволяют задавать независимый от настроек системы паттерн.

Таким образом, если вы задаете спецификатор "F" или "f", то строка которую увидит конечный пользователь будет иметь такой же формат, который он наблюдает в большинстве программ и который ему привычен.

Но иногда, спецификация явно указывает выводить данные в строго определенном формате для всех пользователей. В таком случае, следует задавать пользовательский формат. Например: `dddd, MMMM, d, yyyy`